# Custom TableView Cell with UIButton and UILabel

Tags: xamarin.ios

First Problem:
i have a custom TableViewCell with one Label and two Buttons in it.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();    
    this.btnChecked.TouchUpInside+= HandleBtnCheckedhandleTouchUpInside;
    this.btnNotChecked.TouchUpInside += HandleBtnNotCheckedhandleTouchUpInside;
}
```

And here are the Events

```
void HandleBtnNotCheckedhandleTapGestureRecognizerDelegateTouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ButtonClicked");
    }
```

But if i click on the UIButton in the UITableCell my Event won´t be raised.

Second Problem: How can i change the FontSize of a UILabel in code behind?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do it like this:

```
this.btnChecked.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => 
{
    HandleButtonMethod();
};

void HandleButtonMethod()
{
   Console.WriteLine("ButtonClicked");
}
```

To change the fond of a Lable do something like this:

```
label.Font = UIFont.FromName("Arial", 20);
```

Comment: Okay changing the label Font works now, But the Events don´t work.

Comment: how did you put the button in the cell? did you add it as a subView? try doing this: in GetCell go and configure the cell like cell.ContentView.AddSubview(controller.yourbutton)

Comment: I builded it in Interface Builder Like this Tutorial: http://blog.theunical.com/databases/mysql/simon-says-monotouch-lets-build-a-custom-uitableviewcell/

Comment: i usually do it by coding. try putting your elements into a structure and try calling the structure

Comment: can you tell me how to do it by coding? It needs to be a TableCell with two UIButtons and one UILabel

Comment: check this link: http://primates.ximian.com/~miguel/tmp/monocatalog/controls.cs if you want to put more things in a cell just add them to a uiview

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. But i dont think it´s verry good.

I have made a CustomTableCell class

```
public partial class CSTableCell : UIViewController
```

In my DataSource class I override the GetCell() Method

```
        if(cell == null)
        {
            cellController = new CSTableCell();
            NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("CSTableCell", cellController, null);
            cell = cellController.Cell;
            cell.Tag = Environment.TickCount;
            _controllers.Add(cell.Tag, cellController);
        }
        else
        {
            cellController = _controllers[cell.Tag];
        }

        cellController.FontSize = _fontSize;
        cellController.Text = _items[indexPath.Row];

        cellController.BtnChecked.TouchUpInside+=(s,e)=>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Touched");
        };
```

Now my TouchUpInsideEvent works.

But i´m not sure if this is a good solution. And why this Event doesnt work in my TableCell class??